# How to do a join using a join table?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 4 tables, `Vendor`, `Products` and `ProductGroupings` and a join table called `Products_ProductGroupings`. I'm trying to query all `ProductGroupings` joining with `Products` on `Products_ProductGroupings` where `Products.vendor == <A Vendor Instance>`.

What I can't do is find the right syntax to use with the join table.

Alternatively, since `ProductGroupings` has a property called `products` I'd like to query all `ProductGroupings` whose `products` have `vendor` `<A Vendor Instance>`.

```
class Products(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'products'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('products.id'))
    parent = db.relationship('Products', backref='children', remote_side=[id])
    groupings = db.relationship('ProductGroupings', secondary=Products_ProductGroupings, backref='products')


class ProductGroupings(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'product_groupings'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.now)


Products_ProductGroupings = db.Table(
    'products_product_groupings',
    db.Column('product_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('products.id')),
    db.Column('product_grouping_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product_groupings.id'))
)

class Vendors(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'vendors'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    hash = db.Column(db.Text(10), nullable=False, default=create_hash)
    vendor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Vendors.id), nullable=False)
    vendor = db.relationship(Vendors, backref='products', foreign_keys=[vendor_id])
```

Comment: Post (relevant parts of) your models.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Added models.

Comment: I think you've omitted the relationship / foreign keys between Products and Vendors

Comment: @IljaEverilä Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply join along the ORM relationship:

```
db.session.query(ProductGroupings).\
    join(ProductGroupings.products).\
    filter(Products.vendor == v)
```

Alternatively [`Query.join()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join) accepts a join point as the second argument:

```
db.session.query(ProductGroupings).\
    join(Products, ProductGroupings.products).\
    filter(Products.vendor == v)
```

Note that the many to many relationship may end up producing multiple rows for a single `ProductGroupings` entity, but this is not visible when querying just a single entity. You could also [filter on EXISTS](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#using-exists):

```
db.session.query(ProductGroupings).\
    filter(ProductGroupings.products.any(Products.vendor == v))
```